# How to let Linux execute a php file per 5 minutes thread safety?

Tags: linux, xshell

I have a `scree.php` file in the path:

```
xxx/.../Home/scree.php
```

I want to execute it per 5 minutes, and make sure it is thread-safety. How to do that?

I am under XShell.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using crontab.

1. Type "crontab -e" in your terminal.
2. Paste in the following code:

   */5 * * * * php /Home/scree.php
3. Exit out of your editor.

Learn more about crontab [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the crontab in XShell:

```
crontab -e
```

Then in the file, you should add the code:

```
*/5 * * * * root usr/bin/php xxx/.../Home/scree.php
```

Then esc `:wq` out of the file.

If it shows:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
```

means success.